# Redux store shape : Not getting the correct redux store/state shape

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am not able to get the correct redux store/state shape .

I have 2 reducer functions for images and videos as below -

imageReducer.js -

```
const initialState = {
  images:{
    imageArray:[],
    selectedImage:{}
  }
}

export default function (state = initialState,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state, 
        images: {
        ...state.images.imageArray,...action.images
      }
    }
    case types.SELECTED_IMAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        images: {
          ...state.images.selectedImage,...action.image
        }
      }
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

videoReducer.js -

```
const initialState = {
  videos:{
    videoArray:[],
    selectedVideo:{}
  }
}

export default function (state = initialState,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state, 
        videos: {
        ...state.videos.videoArray,...action.videos
      }
    }
    case types.SELECTED_VIDEO:
      return {
        ...state,
        images: {
          ...state.videos.selectedVideo,...action.video
        }
      }
       default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Root reducer -

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import img from './imageReducer';
import vid from './videoReducer';

// Combines all reducers to a single reducer function
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  img, 
  vid
});
```

The final redux state I am getting doesn't match with the shape of the initialState , I am expecting my final state shape to be as that of initialState passed to the reducer function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducers are actually creating a different structure when returning data. Changing the reducers to this should fix the issue.

```
const initialState = {
  images:{
    imageArray:[],
    selectedImage:{}
  }
}

export default function (state = initialState,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return { 
        images: {
        ...state.images,
        imageArray: [
            ...state.images.imageArray,...action.images
         ]
      }
    }
case types.SELECTED_IMAGE:
      return {
        images: {
          ...state.images,
          selectedImage: {
            ...state.images.selectedImage, ...action.image
          }

        }
      }
      default:
        return state;
   }  
  }
}
```

and same for video reducer. Also, I think it is better to remove the `images` and `videos` keys from the state object so that you can call `props.img.imageArray` rather than calling `props.img.images.imageArray`.

Hope this helps

Comment: your code is throwing an error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.imageArray is not iterable

Comment: @Vishwanath my bad, it should  be `...state.images.imageArray`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks resolved my issue , and yes I removed the the images and video keys from the state object

Comment: @Vishwanath You are welcome. Glad that I could help.